# How to use AwesomeWM signals in lua?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I want to execute a method when one of my `wibox.widget.textbox` widgets is clicked, and according to [the documentation](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.widget.textclock.html#Signals) I should use the `button::press` *signal*.

However I didn't find anything about these signals, I can't even figure *if it is a native lua thing of if they are tied with AwesomeWM.*

Thus, I don't know how to implement them.
Any help would be appreciated. (Please note that I have barely no knowledge in lua).

Sample code:

```
mywidget = wibox.widget.textbox()
mywidget:set_align("right")
-- I want to execute awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pavucontrol") if the widget is clicked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this.  The `button::press` signal needs a callback which is called with the parameters listed in the docs you linked.  Untested:

```
local box = wibox.widget.textbox(...)
local box_pressed = function(lx, ly, button, mods, find_widgets_result)
    // some code ...
end
box:connect_signal("button::press", box_pressed)
```